# Angular components updating from web socket messages

Tags: angular, websocket, data-binding, observable

I'm trying to get and update data in my frontend angular app from a web socket written in swift vapor. The backend is also written by me, so I can edit anything.
When frontend first connects the socket sends all needed data (in this case a big JSON object containing sub-objects which in turn have sub objects etc...).

```
{
  "alpha": {
    "isUsingXXX": true,
    "loopbacks": [
      "10.50.255.1",
      "10.50.255.11"
    ],
    "hasLte": false,
    "isUsingLte": false,
    "virtualLink": {
      "links": {
        "Bravo <-> XXX": {
          "gradeUpdates": {
            "up": {
              "174": {
                "message": "Test message",
                "grade": "BAD",
                "progressive": 174,
                "date": "2022-11-03T08:13:54Z"
              }
            },
            "down": {
              "175": {
                "message": "Test message",
                "grade": "BAD",
                "progressive": 175,
                "date": "2022-11-03T08:13:54Z"
              }
            }
          },
          "congestionUpdates": {
            "173": {
              "message": "Test message",
              "congestion": "CONGESTED",
              "progressive": 173,
              "date": "2022-11-03T08:13:54Z"
            }
          },
          "statusUpdates": {
            "7": {
              "status": "ACTIVE",
              "message": "Setting initial value",
              "progressive": 7,
              "date": "2022-11-03T08:13:54Z"
            }
          },
          "name": "Bravo <-> XXX"
        },
        "Alpha <-> XXX": {
          "gradeUpdates": {
            "up": {
              "170": {
                "message": "Test message",
                "grade": "GOOD",
                "progressive": 170,
                "date": "2022-11-03T08:13:54Z"
              }
            },
            "down": {
              "171": {
                "message": "Test message",
                "grade": "GOOD",
                "progressive": 171,
                "date": "2022-11-03T08:13:54Z"
              }
            }
          },
          "congestionUpdates": {
            "4": {
              "message": "Setting initial value",
              "congestion": "UNCONGESTED",
              "progressive": 4,
              "date": "2022-11-03T08:13:54Z"
            }
          },
          "statusUpdates": {
            "3": {
              "status": "ACTIVE",
              "message": "Setting initial value",
              "progressive": 3,
              "date": "2022-11-03T08:13:54Z"
            }
          },
          "name": "Alpha <-> XXX"
        }
      },
      "gradeUpdates": {
        "176": {
          "message": "Test message",
          "grade": "BAD",
          "progressive": 176,
          "date": "2022-11-03T08:13:54Z"
        }
      }
    },
    "statusUpdates": {
      "1667463234643": {
        "status": "SAILING",
        "date": "2022-11-03T08:13:54Z"
      }
    },
    "pings": {
      "1667463234643": {
        "latency": 675,
        "date": "2022-11-03T08:13:54Z"
      }
    },
    "hasXXX": true,
    "name": "Alpha",
    "codename": "alpha"
  },
  "bravo":{...},
  "charlie":{...}
}
```

Now, what I'm trying to achieve is the update of single sub objects with subsequent socket messages, which are something like

```
{
  "kind":"linkGradeUpdate",
  "codename": "alpha",
  "linkName": "Bravo <-> SantaRosa 107",
  "direction": "up",
  "data":{
    "201": {
      "message": "Update test message",
      "grade": "GOOD",
      "progressive": 201,
      "date": "2022-11-03T08:15:54Z"
    }
  }
}
```

I mean I'm trying to send just necessary data to perform the update adding them to the main received big object.
And everything in my code works except for UI, which I cannot figure out.
I tried to make a component which loops through the data with sub components but I cannot get get data displayed, do I need an `Observable` for that?

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'
import { Ship, Message } from '../interfaces'

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class WebsocketService {
  url = 'ws://localhost:8080/api/socket/session'
  socket: WebSocket
  ships: Map<string, Ship> = new Map()

  constructor() {}

  openSocket() {
    this.socket = new WebSocket(this.url)
    this.socket.onopen = event => {
      console.log(`Open ${event}`)
    }
    this.socket.onmessage = event => {
      const message = JSON.parse(event.data)
      if (this.ships.size == 0) {
        console.log('Inititalizing ships...')
        this.ships = new Map(Object.entries(message))
      } else {
        console.log('Updating ship...')
        this.updateShips(message)
      }
    }
    this.socket.onclose = event => {
      console.log(`Closed ${event}`)
    }
  }

  updateShips(message: Message) {
    let ship: Ship = this.ships.get(message.shipCodename)
    const data = message[message.kind]
    const linkName = message.linkName
    switch (message.kind) {
      case 'shipStatus':
        console.log('Before update')
        ship.statusUpdates[data.progressive] = data
        console.log('After update')
        break
      case 'virtualLinkGrade':
        ship.virtualLink.gradeUpdates[data.progressive] = data
        break
      case 'linkGrade':
        const linkDirection = message.linkDirection
        if (linkDirection == 'UP') {
          ship.virtualLink.links[linkName].gradeUpdates.up[data.progressive] = data
        } else {
          ship.virtualLink.links[linkName].gradeUpdates.down[data.progressive] = data
        }
        break
      case 'linkStatus':
        ship.virtualLink.links[linkName].statusUpdates[data.progressive] = data
        break
      case 'linkCongestion':
        ship.virtualLink.links[linkName].congestionUpdates[data.progressive] = data
        break
    }
  }

  closeSocket() {
    this.socket.close()
  }
}
```

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core'
import { WebsocketService } from 'src/app/services/websocket.service'
import { Ship } from 'src/app/interfaces'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.page.scss']
})
export class DashboardPage implements OnInit {
  ships: Map<string, Ship>

  constructor(private websocket: WebsocketService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.websocket.openSocket()
    this.ships = this.websocket.ships
    console.log(this.ships)
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.websocket.closeSocket()
  }
}
```

Now, I understand that data is updated after ngOnInit(), so I can see data in console but not in the rendered view.
My question is: do I need an `Observable<Map<string, Ship>>`, or `Map<string, Observable<Ship>>` to re-render just updated chunks of data? Or maybe something totally different...
Thanks, I hope I've been clear enough...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your service you are reassigning the `ships` property: `this.ships = new Map(Object.entries(message))`, but you only grab the contents of this property once in the `ngOnInit` function of the component that uses it.

To make sure that your component can get the updated ship data, you could make the `ships` property have a type `Subject` (similar to `Observable`), then subscribe to it in your component. Here's some code that should point you in the right direction:

**Service**

```
export class WebsocketService {
  ships: Subject<Map<string, Ship>> = new Subject();

  private shipData: Map<string, Ship> = new Map<string, Ship>();

  constructor() {}

  openSocket() {
    // ...

    this.socket.onmessage = event => {
      const message = JSON.parse(event.data)
      if (this.ships.size == 0) {
        console.log('Inititalizing ships...')
        this.shipData = new Map(Object.entries(message));
        this.ships.next(this.shipData);
        //         ^^^^ <= key part
      } else {
        console.log('Updating ship...')
        this.updateShips(message)
      }
    }
  }

  updateShips(message: Message) {
    let ship: Ship = this.shipData.get(message.shipCodename)

    // ...

    this.ships.next(this.shipData);
  }
}
```

Note: for the `updateShips` method to work, we need to store a copy of the last ship data in the service, and send it through the Subject when it changes.

**Component**

```
  ships: Map<string, Ship>
  shipsSubscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private websocket: WebsocketService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.websocket.openSocket()
    this.shipsSubscription = this.websocket.ships.subscribe(ships => {
      this.ships = ships;
      console.log(this.ships)
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.websocket.closeSocket()

    // It's a good idea to remove subscriptions when the component is destroyed
    if (this.shipsSubscription) {
      this.shipsSubscription.unsubscribe();
    }
  }
```

This will ensure that your component gets the latest ships data whenever it it sent from the server.